# OSError: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed, while loading torchtrt_runtime.dll in Python 3.10

Tags: python, c++, dll, pytorch, tensorrt

I was trying to load a compiled torch_tensorRT module on C++ and python.

In C++ I am loading it with:

```
const torch::Device device = torch::Device(torch::kCUDA, 0);
model = torch::jit::load(model_path, device);
```

In python I am loading it with:

```
torch.jit.load(model_path)
```

On C++ it worked fine on Debug mode, but on C++ Release mode and In Python it throwed following error:

> RuntimeError: Unknown type name 'torch.torch.classes.tensorrt.Engine':
> File "code/torch/movinets/models.py", line 4 parameters = [] buffers =
> []
> _torch___movinets_models_MoViNet_trt_engine : torch.torch.classes.tensorrt.Engine < -- HERE   def forward(self_1:
> torch.movinets.models.MoViNet_trt, input_0: Tensor) -> Tensor:

However when I loaded torchtrt_runtime.dll on C++ release with following code, torch_tensorRT module got loaded perfectly:

```
HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("torchtrt_runtime"));
    if (hLib == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Library torchtrt_runtime.dll not found" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

This makes it clear that running on windows need torchtrt_runtime.dll to be loaded. However when I'm trying to load torchtrt_runtime.dll in python with following code:

```
torch.ops.load_library("torchtrt_runtime.dll")

or

import ctypes
hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL("torchtrt_runtime.dll") or ctypes.CDLL("torchtrt_runtime.dll")
```

Library is not getting loaded and throwing following error:

> hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("torchtrt_runtime.dll") File
> "C:\Users\NomanAnjum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py",
> line 374, in **init** self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'torchtrt_runtime.dll' (or
> one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor
> syntax.

I then used dependancy checker for torchtrt_runtime.dll and added all dependant dlls to same folder and error has changed to:

> File "video_play.py", line 198, in get_torch_tensorrt_converted_model
> hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"torchtrt_runtime.dll") File
> "C:\Users\NomanAnjum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py",
> line 374, in **init** self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization
> routine failed

I have this strong feeling that if I can load torchtrt_runtime.dll in python, it will run.

Please help me on this